# Find all primes p in the interval $[1, 4000]$, such that $2^{(p-1)}$ is congruent with $1\,\,(\mathrm{mod} \,\, p ^ 2)$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was checking the following number theory exercise:

> Find all primes $p$ in the interval $[1, 4000]$, such that $2^{(p-1)}$ is
>   congruent with $1\,\,(\mathrm{mod} \,\, p^2)$.

Any clue or help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What tools are you expected to have available to you? This is very straightforward as a programming exercise...

Comment: Sage delivers after `[ p for p in primes(4000) if 2^(p-1) % (p^2) == 1 ]` the list `[1093, 3511]` .

Comment: Such primes are called Wieferich-primes. Only the ones mentioned by dan fulea are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such primes are called [Wieferich primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime).

The only known Wieferich primes are $1093$ and $3511$ ([OEIS/A001220](https://oeis.org/A001220)).